# Searches lock up in MS Access on my linked SQL tables - what is the cause?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Searches lock up in Access on my linked SQL tables. It will work if it is a top to bottom search but it has loop through to bottom then back up to top is locks up. My frontend is connectedt to a hosted SQL backend via ODBC. Here are some pictures of what's happening:

[first image of search not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ1Xm.png)

[second image of it working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuNmT.png)

Comment: i wouldn't really recommend using access native search methods. Especially if your linked table is large enough. Why don't you create another front-end for searching? much much faster than access. Also why are you allowing direct table edits ?

Comment: Will your users be searching for a vin this way? (hopefully not).